# How to redirect from https non www to https www?

Tags: web, https

I need quick, suggestion.
My site is working https://example.com and I want to redirect it on https://www.example.com. 
Please help me.

Comment: google redirecting with .htaccess

Comment: I have tried many quires but did get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html